# Bash echo multi line to end of file but dont echo in terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm writing a custom alias function to create my vhosts for me whenever i'm creating a new web project. In my function, I want to paste an entire new virtual host into my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. I'm first asking for an input for the domain name and folder name to create like this

```
read -p 'Please enter the domain for your new site: ' domain;
read -p 'Please enter the folder name for your new site: ' folder;
```

and then in my function, i'm writing to my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like this

```
echo "
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin $domain
     DocumentRoot \"/Users/sam/Development/Websites/$folder\"
     ServerName $domain
     ErrorLog \"/usr/local/var/log/httpd/$folder/error_log\"
     CustomLog \"/usr/local/var/log/httpd/$folder/access_log\" common
   </VirtualHost>" | sudo tee -a /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf;
```

But i've noticed this echo's in the terminal as well as in the `conf` file. The function works perfectly, but how do I get it to NOT echo in the terminal?

Do I have to use something other than `echo` to append to the file to achieve this?

Comment: `tee`'s *purpose* is to write both to a file *and to stdout* (it's like a pipe tee: you've got water coming in one way, and going out two ways). Using `sudo tee` to escalate privileges used for the opening-a-file side is a side effect, not the primary use/design case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `tee` you may consider to use `>>`

```
sudo sh -c "echo \"
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin $domain
     DocumentRoot \"/Users/sam/Development/Websites/$folder\"
     ServerName $domain
     ErrorLog \"/usr/local/var/log/httpd/$folder/error_log\"
     CustomLog \"/usr/local/var/log/httpd/$folder/access_log\" common
   </VirtualHost>\" >> test2.out"
```

Comment: I just get 'permission denied' using this method?

Comment: I made a small change, can you try again?

Comment: This works, but is there any reason why using this method would still throw a `permission` error when using it on `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: there is nothing related with `/etc/hosts` here. It is uncommon and I couldn't reproduce it

Comment: Running `sudo sh -c "..."` is a major security bug (with a non-constant string, using double quotes to substitute into the argument immediately following `-c`). If you have, say `folder='$(rm -rf /*)'`, that expansion will be run as root after the string is substituted into an argument passed to `sh -c`. It's far safer to use [that other guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621033/14122), escalating privileges only for the `tee`.

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect to `/dev/null`:

```
echo "
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin $domain
     DocumentRoot \"/Users/sam/Development/Websites/$folder\"
     ServerName $domain
     ErrorLog \"/usr/local/var/log/httpd/$folder/error_log\"
     CustomLog \"/usr/local/var/log/httpd/$folder/access_log\" common
   </VirtualHost>" | sudo tee -a /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf > /dev/null
```

This allows you to append with `sudo` privileges while also not showing the output on screen.